# Calculate a line integral using Green's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I am asked to compute the integral:
$$\oint_{\gamma}(xy^2+\frac{1}{x}+y)\mathrm{d}x+(y\ln{x}+x+\frac{2}{y})\mathrm{d}y$$
where $\gamma$ is the positively oriented boundary of $D=\{x,y\geq0, x\leq y\leq 2x, 1\leq xy\leq 4\}$.

My thoughts are using the Green's theorem since $\gamma$ is closed and are piece wise smooth, simple closed curve. The integral equals to:
$$\iint \left( \frac{y}{x}-2xy\right) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$
Then using substitution $u=\frac{y}{x}, v=xy,  dxdy=-2u\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$. The integral equals to:
$$\iint_{1\leq u\leq 2, 1\leq v\leq 4} (u-2v)(-2u)\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$
Which calculates to be $31$ if I am not mistaken, but the correct answer is $\frac{3}{2}(1-5\ln{2})$. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in computing $dx  dy$. Also, note that it is clearly wrong because somehow, you found that the **absolute value** of the determinant of the Jacobian is $-2u < 0$.

The correct relationship is that
\begin{align}
dx dy &= \left| \det 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \partial x/ \partial u & \partial x/ \partial v \\
\partial y/ \partial u & \partial y/ \partial v
\end{pmatrix}
\right| du dv
\end{align}
If you invert things properly, you should find that $x = u^{-1/2} v^{1/2}$ and $y = u^{1/2} v^{1/2}$. So, the determinant of the matrix above is $-\frac{1}{2u}$. Taking absolute value (AND using the fact that $u \in [1,2]$) yields:
\begin{align}
dx dy &= \dfrac{1}{2u} \, dudv
\end{align}
Now you should get the correct answer.

Comment: You don't actually have to invert the transformation (although it's manageable here). By the chain rule, you can just take the reciprocal of the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant of $u,v$ in terms of $x,y$, written as a function of $u,v$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right, I was aware I could do it that way as well, but when I was solving the problem, I kept doing the algebra incorrectly for some reason and couldn't figure out where. Hence this long method. (btw, your lectures have been a wonderful companion to Spivak's Calculus on manifolds (especially the part about IFT's and manifolds), I really enjoyed them :) )

Comment: Thank you both so very much! I can't believe I didn't notice that it is the inverse of the transformation until now.